# how to concatenate two column value before inserting in table n store same same table at same time

Tags: php, mysql, insert, concatenation

I want to concatenate two Textbox values and store the same table in different name, while inserting a query

for Example

```
$Standard= $_POST['Standard'];
$division = $_POST['division'];
$RollNo = $_POST['RollNo'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];
$Class_ID = $Standard.$division.$Year;
$Student_ID = $Class_ID.$RollNo;

<form action="#" method="POST">

            <label>Standard</label> 
            <input type="text" name="Standard"> 

            <label>division</label> 
            <input type="text" name="division"> 

            <label>Roll No</label> 
            <input type="text" name="RollNo"> 
            <label>Year</label> 
            <?php
            $already_selected_value = 1984;
            $earliest_year = 1990;
            print '<select name="Year">';
            foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
            print '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x === $already_selected_value ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$x.'</option>';
                }
                print '</select>';
            ?>
        </div> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default w3ls-button" name="button">Submit</button> 
    </form>
```

Here I have the `Textbox` for standard, division, `RollNo` and `Year` and I created a variable for taking data from text box. But here I also created two extra variables `$Class_ID`, `$Student_ID` in class_Id and I want to concatenate `$Standard+$division+$Year` and in `$Student_ID = $Class_ID+$RollNO` then after I want insert all value in table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `class`(Student_ID, Class_ID, Standard, division, RollNo, Year) VALUES ('$Student_ID','$Class_ID','$Standard','$division','$RollNo','$Year')";
```

Comment: the simple answer is that there is no need. In fact you shouldn't do this. You are just duplicating data.

Comment: but i want to generate auto key by giving std,div and roll value.

Comment: just make them a together unique field or the primary key. But now adays non integer primary keys have fallen out of style